# Basic notation question

Tags: sequences-and-series

Forgive my ignorance, but can someone explain how the notation works in this formula:
$$\begin{align*}
b_{k} = \begin{cases} 1 & k = 1, 2 \\
\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k-2}(2^{k-j-1}-1) \, b_{j} & k\geq 3.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$
This is supposed to give the bisection of the Lucas sequence with two ones prepended, but I can't figure out how to read it. (What is $j$ and what is $k$, how does the sum fit in?)

Also what is this notation called (and can you point me to some resource to read about it)?
Thank you

Comment: $k$ is an arbitrary integer greater than $3$. $j$ is the index of summation, so you are supposed to take all values of $j$ from $1$ through $k-2$, and add the terms in the expression. This defines $b(k)$ in terms of $b(1)$, $b(2),\ldots,b(k-2)$. So $b(3)$ is defined in terms of $b(1)$; $b(4)$ is defined in terms of $b(1)$ and $b(2)$, etc.

Comment: See [Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation).

Comment: This is just like piecewise functions.

Comment: The $k$ in $b_k$ just means it is the $k$ term.  The definition is telling you the first and second term are equal to $1$ and it is giving you a formula to calculate the third and later terms.  The formula is: to calculate the $k$th term, add up a sum.  There are $k-2$ terms to add up.  The first term to add up is $(2^{k-2}-1)b_1$.  The second term to add up is $(2^{k-3}-1)b_2$ and the third term to add up is $(2^{k-4}-1)b_3$ etc. upto $(2-1)b_{k-2}$.  So the $j$th term to add up is $(2^{k-(j+1)}-1)b_j$. $j$ is the index for the summands of the sum required for the $k$th term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In
\begin{align*}
b_{k} = \begin{cases} 1 & k = 1, 2 \\
\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k-2}(2^{k-j-1}-1) \, b_{j} & k\geq 3.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
the notation reads as $b_{1}=1$, $b_{2}=1$, which are the first two terms in the sequence, followed by additional terms being obtained from the relation, where $k$ is the index representing the term location and $j$ being the index of the summation,
$$ b_{n} = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-2} (2^{n-j-1} -1) \, b_{j}.$$

For $n=3$ this is
$$ b_{3} = \sum_{j=1}^{1} (2^{2-j}-1) \, b_{j} = (2^{2-1}-1) \, b_{1} = 1 \cdot 1 = 1.$$
For $n=4$ the is
$$b_{4} = \sum_{j=1}^{2} (2^{3-j}-1) \, b_{j} = (2^{2}-1) \, b_{1} + (2^{1}-1) \, b_{2} = 3 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 1 = 4. $$
Continuing this process the next few terms give
$$ b_{n} \in \{1, 1, 1, 4, 11, 29, 76, 199, 521, \cdots \}. $$
Comparing this to sequences in the Oeis leads to [A002878](https://oeis.org/A002878) with $\{1, 1 \}$ prepended.